# How to use JavaScript classes in different files from HTML and still work on IOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, laravel

I am currently in a situation where I need to use classes from JavaScript within different js files. In this case, I have a class called `Panel` within the file `js/radar-home.js`. This is how I currently use the class from within my HTML file:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/radar-home.js') }}"></script>
<script>
        try{
            var panel1 = new Panel(args);
        catch(err){
            alert("Internal Error - " + err);
        }
</script>
```

This method works perfectly fine on Windows and Android. It also works on all the browsers I tested, including Chrome. However, when loading this on my iPhone or iPad on Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and the WebDebug app, I get an alert with the message: `Internal Error - RefrenceError: Can't find variable: Panel`.

My environment:

- PHP 7.3.21
- Laravel 6.18.25
- On an Ubuntu 20.04 server
- The source appears identical on both ios and windows browsers.
- CloudFlare (proxied) - However, before I set this up, I still have the exact same issue as well as when I was using HTTP and not HTTPS.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:
I have placed a function within `radar-home.js` not wrapped by a class. This function runs without error on desktop, but it errors on IOS. Output: `RefrenceError Can't find variable: testing123` (`testing123()` was the test function I made).

Comment: Is the script loaded, loading, or did it fail to load when the code runs. Check the debugger

Comment: @AluanHaddad the script loads on desktop. It does not load on IOS.

Comment: If the script defining Panel does not load in the details of how you use it aren't relevant

Comment: @AluanHaddad I agree. I just tested it after you mentioned such.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the code when the DOM is ready. The code is being executed before the radar-home.js is loaded to the page. Try something like:

```
    <script src="{{ asset('js/radar-home.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
      if(document.readyState === "loading") document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', func); else func();
    
      function func(){
          try{
                var panel1 = new Panel(args);
            } catch(err){
                alert("Internal Error - " + err);
            }
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: This seems to work fine for on Windows still, but there was no change when I tried it on an iPad and iPhone. I made sure the cache was cleared, and the source matched both.

Comment: Try to add `type="text/javascript"` to your script tags I have encountered something weird before without it. Also debug you phone browser and make sure the script is being loaded. If you are using es6 classes those are only supported in modern browsers. If so, you may need to convert those into functions with prototypes.
https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class

Comment: Also changed. Same result on three browsers on IOS.

Comment: I think you're using es6 classes like `class Panel {}` which are not fully supported.

Comment: caniuse says it is supported for safari though?

Comment: Try to add babel compiler to your page too. This may fix your issue.
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Added. Issue continues.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the solution to this is something that I probably should have investigated earlier on. This issue occurred only on IOS devices.

Essentially, the scripts were failing to load because of syntax errors or miscellaneous errors which IOS does not parse correctly. Unlike Chrome, Firefox, and many other browsers which do their best to read the JavaScript, IOS is very picky.

After fixing all errors using a [JavaScript validator](http://beautifytools.com/javascript-validator.php) (asides from ES6 errors), everything worked flawlessly on IOS.